# Heroku: upgrading Ruby application from Cedar-14 to Heroku-18

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on upgrading the heroku stack of my Ruby application from Cedar-14 to Heroku-18. The Ruby version of my application is 2.0.0 however the Heroku-18 stack is based on Ubuntu 18.04 requires a higher version of Ruby. As my application uses an older version, upgrading is complex and time consuming.
With that said,

1. Can I still be able to run with the same older versions of Ruby, Ruby Gems and Rails on Heroku-18 stack at my own RISK? As I am still be able to run my application locally on Ubuntu 18.04
2. Does heroku supports SSH to servers for installation of older versions and related plugins like AWS?

Comment: I don't think heroku supports running older versions because Cedar-14 to Heroku-18 is major update which is not backward compatible. For SSH, checkout Heroku Exec which allows secure access to your dynos

Comment: Thank you Vasanth for your response. I tried `heroku ps:exec` for SSH access. I will try if I can update the Ruby version manually.